# view form validation results using codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, url

This is the URL of form.

> http://localhost/cig/index.php/Resetpassword?temporarycode=CLK6xW7j0I1psnk243wF&email=coddy@zack.com

And this is how i validate it.but the problem is that i am unable to show the validation errors on the page

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpassword', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|matches[password]');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

              redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
          }
```

Comment: please also post the view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try CI flash data,

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('errors', validation_errors());

redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

It keeps the data for next server request.

Comment: thanks for this idea. but can you show how to get this in view and show it.

Comment: In view, use $this->session->flashdata('errors'); to show the message

Answer (score 1):

ok i have ran into a couple things that could be improved.

---

for starters why do you redirect the user somewhere when the fields are invalid? why not use:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpassword', 'Password Confirmation', 'required|matches[password]');
if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    redirect(base_url('emailSend'); // or wherever you want the visitor to be send to
} 
$this->load->view('register'); // or however your view file is called
```

---

This way you have no problems with showing errors if you have the rule `<?= validation_errors() ?>` in your view file, the `<?=  ?>` is short php code for `<?php echo ?>` and the `validation_erros()` should contain the validation errors if there are any.

Comment: oh! actually I didn't tried it thinking that it will not cause a problem and not work. But it worked.Thanks

Comment: np glad to help you